# Trying to connect a switch that only has RJ45 ports to a Windows 10 PC that has a fiber NIC and it is not working as expected

Tags: networking, conversion, fiber, cabling

I'm trying to connect a switch that only has RJ45 ports to a Windows 10 PC that has a fiber NIC. When I use an unmanaged media converter, the copper connection is fine, but there's no fiber connection. The PC says the the media is disconnected. However, if I use two media converters (for testing purposes) to go copper - fiber - copper, everything is fine. I use 850nm SFPs, multimode fiber, and Cat6 or Cat6A cables.

Is there anything I can do to make it work? I've tried several media converters with the same results.

This is the list of equipment:

- **Media converters**: 10Gtek G101-SFP, and UMS-1F1T from FS.com
- **SFPs**: HiFiber AXS85-192-M3 10GBase-SR SFP+ 850nm, IBM 78P2492 850nm, and 10Gtek AXS85-192-M3 10GBase-SR SFP+ 850nm
- **NIC**: 10Gtek 10Gb PCI-E NIC
  Network Card, Single SFP+ Port, with Intel 82599EN Controller

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Did you program these media converters? How did you determine the copper connection was “fine”?

Comment: They are unmanaged, I can't program them. The copper connection was fine because the copper connection light was on.

Comment: Do the media converters have integrated optics or do they take the same SFPs as you're using with the NIC? What specific SFP model, what media converters, and what specific NIC do you have?

Comment: The media converters take SFPs. I've tried a 10Gtek G101-SFP and a UMS-1F1T from FS.com. They work fine together. The SFPs I've used are HiFiber AXS85-192-M3 10GBase-SR SFP+ 850nm, IBM 78P2492 850nm, and a 10Gtek AXS85-192-M3 10GBase-SR SFP+ 850nm. The NIC is 10Gtek 10Gb PCI-E NIC Network Card, Single SFP+ Port, with Intel 82599EN Controller.

Comment: Can you please add requested information to the question itself, using the EDIT button? This will help make your question more clear and complete and help others who may have answers for you.